# Creating a filter for A* search algorithm

Tags: c

Let's say I am trying to solve a problem using A* search.

Let's say I have a node :

```
struct node {
    int tiles[N][N];
    int f, g, h;
    short zero_row, zero_column;    /* location (row and colum) of blank tile 0 */
    struct node *next;
    struct node *parent;            /* used to trace back the solution */
};
```

Now, let's say that I have a list of nopdes,

```
struct node *open = NULL, *closed = NULL;
struct node *succ_nodes[4];
```

but let's say that sometimes, Nodes that are in succ_node sometimes get juxtaposed with open and closed. So,  I would need a filter function to keep them away from one another.

I have created this filter so far:

```
void filter(int i, struct node *pnode_list){
    if(nodes_same(*pnode_list, succ_nodes[i]) == TRUE)
    *pnode_list = *pnode_list->next; 
}
```

Is this a good filter, or can it be improved upon? If so, then how?